# Add Quicksand for mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile

I am using Quicksand from [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Quicksand)for my [portfolio site](http://www.richardclifford.net).  When I look at the site on mobile devices the font is not Quicksand.
When I resize screen on desktop the font is correct but as soon as on devices its different.
I thought Google fonts worked on mobile devices so this is why I'm stumped on this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated on this.

Comment: Downvoted, as there is no much point in asking "something not working, help!" wiithout showing the code., You first need to debug your site to find the specific area in the code which fails and ask questions about it while adding it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have a reference to Google Fonts Quicksand stylesheet on your site. I would suppose that you have Quicksand installed on your PC and as a result it can be seen but you wouldn't have it on your mobile and so it wouldn't display.

Either add the following to your site via wp_enqueue_style:

```
 https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand
```

Or alternatively try one of the many Google Font plugins available for WordPress.